# How do I create an Azure CustomScriptExtension with the .net SDK?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk-.net

There's a powershell commandlet for custom script extensions seems to support a bunch of nice parameter options, but the .net client API for VM extensions doesn't have such a nice strongly typed set of parameters to configure, and requires using these publicSettings/privateSettings things... whats the right way to do it with .net APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Using the new fluent SDK this is my best attempt so far...:

```
var blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(
    new Uri(tenantStorageAccount.EndPoints.Primary.Blob),
    new StorageCredentials(tenantStorageAccount.Name, tenantStorageKeys.First().Value));

var scriptText = @"Write-Host ""Success!""
```

";

```
var bootContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("boot");
await bootContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
var bootstrapBlob = bootContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("bootstrap.ps1");
await bootstrapBlob.UploadTextAsync(scriptText);

var sasToken = bootstrapBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(
   new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
   {
       SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1),
       Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
   });

string bootstrapBlobSasUri = bootstrapBlob.Uri + sasToken;

var extensionTasks = new List<Task<IVirtualMachine>>();
await vms.ForEachAsync(async vm =>
{
    await vm.Update().DefineNewExtension("bootstrapper")
       .WithPublisher("Microsoft.Compute")
       .WithType("CustomScriptExtension")
       .WithVersion("1.8")
       .WithPublicSetting("fileUris", new string[] { bootstrapBlobSasUri })
       .WithProtectedSetting("storageAccountName", tenantStorageAccount.Name)
       .WithProtectedSetting("storageAccountKey", tenantStorageKeys[0])
       .WithProtectedSetting("commandToExecute", "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File bootstrap.ps1")
       .Attach().ApplyAsync();
});
```